# autocomplete algorithms, papers, strategies, etc

Tags: autocomplete

I'm wondering if anyone has good resources to read or code to experiment for "autcomplete"

I would like to know what's the theory behind autocompletion, where to start what are the commonn mistakes etc.

I found fascinating the way products like Enso, Launchy, Google chrome and even tcsh perform their auto complete, I started my self just for curiosity some sample code and I got to the conclusion this must be a field widely explored before.

I would appreciate if someone shares any good technical resource on how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- http://humanized.com/weblog/2007/03/30/what_makes_a_good_autocomplete/   --
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/2ccb37b9-c7e1-4113-86ac-ad3d33b4b4b1/ -- in the .Net world
- A *nasty* patent on autocompletion approach (still possibly worth   reading for the *theory*) http://www.patentstorm.us/patents/5845300/description.html
- http://ask.metafilter.com/91068/Fuzzy-text-completion-algorithm for a high level discussion on strategies to take.

Comment: Looks like a useful list of URLs - thanks.  I'll have to explore sometime - when I have time (and oh, look, there's a pig flying round a rhubarb tree!)

Comment: what is this rhubarb tree mumbojumbo?

Comment: http://humanized.com/weblog/2007/03/30/what_makes_a_good_autocomplete/  is an excellent resource indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blog on implementing autocomplete using GWT:

http://jroller.com/glongman/entry/gwt_autocompleter

But I would recommend you first start with something very simple on your own to grasp how the implementation is done. I'd start with a Trie, maybe even stored completely on the client, then progress to optimizing with server queries if you think they're necessary.

Comment: That link now redirects to a suspicious casino website.

Answer (score 1):

It is an open problem and there are dozen of strategies based on situations. based on my knowledge, I list a short highlights of some of well known Auto Completion strategies and their corresponding data structures. also I tried to summarizing their major ***pros*** and ***cons*** related to **Auto Completion** problem.

**Brute Force** :

- ***pros***: can achieved by checking all universe(input) as the next step
- ***pros***: super easy
- ***pros***: it's good for tiny dataset with limited states
- ***cons***: connections doesn't stored so each time you have to perform a search
- ***cons***: has the worst time complexity.

---

**[Prefixed Tree( Trie )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** :

### [image: Trie from Wikipedia]

- ***pros***: it is the simplest data structure designed for these kind of problems.
- ***pros***: list of all available next states are stored in each state.
- ***cons***: data size should be small( at most should be a low fractional of RAM size).

---

**[Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)** :

Trie has space problem so other data structures main goal is reducing the space complexity. [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) is one of the options. by using DAG you can merge all similar subpath to only one. as a result much of space will be reserved.

[image: Directed Acyclic Graph]

[fast-autocomplete](https://github.com/seperman/fast-autocomplete) repository is in this area which uses Directed Word Graph (DWG) and Levenshtein Edit Distance.

---

**Some other Tree options** :

On each state(or Node) there is a search problem. linear search is the worst case option so most strategies improved their search time by using either sorting( *O(nlog(n)* ) and then using [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)( *O(log(n)*) ) or using a hashtable ( *O(1)*, fast but has more space complexity). encountering so many trade-off dilemmas, other tree data structure variants like [Radix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), [Suggest Tree](http://suggesttree.sourceforge.net/) and [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) may come useful.

**Prioritizig Offers** :
[Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) can be used to prioritize next states. it stores connection probabilities which leads to more accurate results.

### [image: Markov Chain]

**Artificial Intelligence strategies**:

- ***pros***: good models are small and running fast.
- ***pros***: good models just stores discriminative features.
- ***pros***: huge dataset friedly
- ***pros***: Natural Language Processing (NLP ) frameworks has predefined algorithms (higher level API)
- ***pros***: long term learning power is greatly increased.
- ***cons***: understanding input topology is important.
- ***cons***: preprocessing is hard process.
- ***cons***: training time is long.
- ***cons***: convergence may needs too many retrying and retraining which is a hard process.

---

**[Long short term memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) (LSTM )** :

there are so many useful Machine Learning and Deep Learning strategies. a good strategy, you can consider Auto Completion as a time series problem so you can use some models like LSTM.

[image: LSTM]

---

**Transformers** :

The last but not least, I recommend [Transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_(machine_learning_model)) models. currently they are game changers. a great Transformer based language model is [Google BERT](https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/11/open-sourcing-bert-state-of-art-pre.html). it is highly promising on predicting future sequences.
[image: Google BERT]

I also recommend, before starting your Auto Completion project using transformers, please take a look at [python_autocomplete](https://github.com/labmlai/python_autocomplete) repository which uses Transformers and LSTMs to learn Python source code.

---

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is usually implemented using one of the following:

- **Trees**. By indexing the searchable text in a tree structure (prefix tree, suffix tree, dawg, etc..) one can execute very fast searches at the expense of memory storage. The tree traversal can be adapted for approximate matching.
- **Pattern Partitioning**. By partitioning the text into tokens (ngrams) one can execute searches for pattern occurrences using a simple hashing scheme.
- **Filtering**. Find a set of potential matches and then apply a sequential algorithm to check each candidate.

A couple of papers about the subject:

- Bořivoj Melichar. Approximate String Matching by Finite Automata;
- Gonzalo Navarro. A Guided Tour to Approximate String Matching;
- Leonid Boytsov. Indexing Methods for Approximate Dictionary Searching: Comparative Analysis;
- Marios Hadjieleftheriou and Divesh Srivastava. Approximate String Processing;
- Surajit Chaudhuri and Raghav Kaushik. Extending Autocompletion To Tolerate Errors;

Take a look at [completely](https://github.com/fmmfonseca/completely), a Java autocomplete library.