# Algorithm used for auto-suggestion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Which algorithms or data structures are used in auto-suggest features?

It seems that edit-distance will be used, but again a frequency or score associated with each word should also be considered. For example, consider the tags option on SO's Ask Question page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie):

- every node of the trie has all the children that begins with the value itself, for example: from *"in"* node you can visit the subtree of all strings starting with *"in"*
- in your case you have to consider score so you can first gather all children (traversing the tree) and then sort them according to the score or whatever
- if you really want to keep *Hamming Distance* (edit-distance) you can adapt the trie to build children according to it

Comment: I think TRIE is the best solution for auto suggest. Edit distance is mainly use for spelling correction when one or two letters from the word are missing, deleted or added. I go with Jack answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the links provided in the answers to this stackoverflow question [autocomplete algorithms, papers, strategies, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226963/autocomplete-algorithms-papers-strategies-etc), you may find what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 0):

hi raccha ,
              Autosuggestion system work on recursive Algorithm.Google & facebook are implement this algo in his formation . facebook are use **graph+recursive** type alog. i am give you example for that. if you are type **f** in facebook search bar then you can saw that facebook is search that how many persons or pages which you like or add. first letter is f then it is showing suggestion's