# JTextField AutoComplete

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtable

Hello: How to add AutoComplete String for JTextField, getting auto complte list from Jtable column.

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
JTable table =new JTable();
```

Answer (score 3):

The [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) library has a very handy AutoCompleteDecorator function.

Say you copy the values of your JTable column into an ArrayList called validValues. All you now need for autocompletion on the JTextField myTextField is the following code:

```
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(myTextField, validValues, true);
```

The third argument tells the autocomplete decorator whether you want strict matching, i.e. whether the user is allowed to enter values other than the ones in your JTable column or not.

Comment: @SmartyTwiti: Hello my friend , any idea how I can make `swingX` to allow me more than one result ? it only allows me one autocompletion , and I need more . Thanks !

Comment: This should really be its own question, I think. Anyway, as I see it, the AutoCompleteDecorator holds the entire List of possible values but only displays the first item in the List in a text field. If you use a JComboBox and decorate it, you will see the drop-down list getting smaller with each matched letter.
If you mean more than one match WITHIN ONE textfield (like in tagging fields, where you can get something like "java; c#; renderers" and match each item by itself) I believe you will have to overwrite the ACD's document. Try contacting @Kleopatra for tips on that.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables, Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), a table's default renderer is a `JLabel` and the default editor is a `JTextField`. You'll need to supply a custom editor that is implemented as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/485530/230513) using an [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/226963/230513) suitable to your intended domain.

Comment: See also @mKorbel's related [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+%5Bjava%5D+autocomplete).