# Invoke search in database on each keystroke of JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I want to add a search facility to JTextField, so that when a user enters text to the JTextField, it retrieves related values from the database.  This way, if the user selects that value, it helps avoids duplication of values.

In addition, when I should enter ABCD, it retrieves related keys from the database as (ABCD EFG,ABCD SDLFH, etc....) and the user should select an appropriate one from that.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add some form of autocomplete functionality to your JTextField object.  The question [JTextField AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689695/jtextfield-autocomplete) discusses this as well. The list of valid values is not dynamically retrieved from a database, though you can look at the code samples linked from there and probably change them to do queries when appropriate.

I'd start with getting familiar with how `AutoCompleteDecorator` from the [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) library works (one of the answers from the above question), since the source is available [here](http://java.net/projects/swingx/sources/svn/show/trunk/swingx-autocomplete?rev=4269).

Comment: Thanks @Chris.I got whatever i want.

Answer (score 0):

use this code written by Scott [Example: Adding Autocomplete to JTextField](http://stackabuse.com/example-adding-autocomplete-to-jtextfield/)